# JQWidget with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript, jqwidget

I am new in Type Script so can anybody let me know please.

Is there any way to use JQWidget in Type Script?
Does JQwidget support type Script? 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

No official way.

There are requests for it here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/1738 and here: http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/typescript/

In an official reply from the developers made October 12, 2015, they say that:

> This is not in our development plans. They are public and available on the Roadmap page.

The development plan is here http://www.jqwidgets.com/roadmap/ and it's not included in the current plan (Dec, 2015 – May, 2016.)

Comment: In their Angular integration code, they have a `.d.ts` file tucked away. It's not great and has several errors (I've had to create a separate mitigation `.d.ts` file to fix some things), but it's better than nothing. There's even some interesting undocumented stuff like `createInstance` for making typed instances of widgets. (Also undocumented is the fact that you can use `new jqwidgets.<widgetname>` to create widgets, but it's broken for tabs.)